# Joining 2 metrics with different labels

Tags: promql

I have 2 metrics with tags below:

```
metric1{ValueA=1, ValueB=2}
metrics2(ValueB=2, ValueC=3}
```

I would like to join the 2 metrics, while having all 3 labels.

Is there a way to write the query to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any binary operator with `on` clause containing common labels an `group_left` containing label present only in the second metric.

For example:

```
metric1 * on (ValueB) group_left(ValueC) metrics2
```

Here `*` is arbitrary operator and you can use any, depending on your expectation about values of resulting time series.

Result will be:

```
{ValueA=1, ValueB=2, ValueC=3}
```

Comment: Is there a way to join all labels without specifying ValueC in group_left?

Comment: @Muzammil, no. But you can join the other way around if you know name of labels in the LHS.